# CakePHP: Search for products after we have the array of categories' ID

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

at the moment I have a list of products and each product has an array of categories (every array has a least 1 category object), I also made a filter for the categories so when I chose them as checkboxes then clicked submit, I'll get an array of the categories' ID. But now I don't really know how I can retrieve all the resources that have categories that match with the filtered ones. I'm very sorry if my explanation is not very clear.

Here is my code:

> **filter.php**

```
<section class="section service border-top">
    <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['novalidate' => true, 'type' => 'get']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->control('categories._ids', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $categories));?>
    </fieldset>
    </br>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Filter'), ['class' =>'logbtn']) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</section>
```

> **productsController.php**

```
public function customerAllProducts()
    {
        $products = $this->paginate($this->Products);

        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ["Categories"],
        ];

        $categories_filter = $this->request->getQuery('categories._ids');

        if(!empty($categories_filter)){
            foreach ($categories_filter as $category_filter){
                echo $category_filter; // Print out all filtered categories' IDs
            }
        }


        $categries = $this->Productss->Categoriess->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('products','categories'));
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You're looking for a way to read all the [products matching the selected categories](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)?

Comment: Yes I am, I’m still struggling with it

Comment: You've tried the `matching` function from the link? Can you update your question to show what you've tried along those lines, and what's not working about it? For example, are you getting an error message, wrong results, just not sure how to access what results you are getting?

Comment: here is what I have changed for the `if(!empty($categories_filter))` statement:

Comment: $query = $productss->find();
$query->matching('Categoriess', function ($q) {
         return $q->where(['Categoriess.id' => $categories_filter]);
 });

Comment: For now, it seems like I'm not sure how I can access the results I want to get

Comment: "Categoriess", not "Categories"? That's weird. But since `$categories_filter` is an array, you need to use `$q->where(['Categoriess.id IN' => $categories_filter]);`

Comment: ok I'll try (oops, Categoriess is just a typo, sorry)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have done it. I have to you IN to filter in the array.